# Is the map $K\otimes_F Hom_F(V, U)\to Hom_K(K\otimes_F V,K\otimes_F U)$ surjective?

Tags: tensor-products

Given  $ U, V$ vectorial space over F and $K/F$ a field extension ( even of infinite degree) the map $K\otimes_F Hom_F(V, U)\to Hom_K(K\otimes_F V,K\otimes_F U)$ is a monomorphism of K vectorial space.  Is it surjective only if $ U, V$ have finite dimension over F ? How can I prove the surjectivity?

Comment: This is kind of a cheap approach. But in the case that $\text{dim}_F U = m$ and $\text{dim}_f V = n$ then $Hom_F(V,U) \cong F^{mn}$ and then $K\otimes_F Hom_F(V,U) \cong K^{mn}$. Similarly, $Hom_K(K\otimes_F V, K\otimes_F U) \cong K^{mn}$. Since they are isomorphic, the map has to be surjective. There are some subtle issues with these isomorphisms not being canonical etc.

Comment: If I put $1\otimes \phi \mapsto \phi_K $ where $ \phi_K(a\otimes v)=a\otimes \phi (v)$ how can I find explicitely a counterimage of some $\psi \in Hom_K(K\otimes_F V,K\otimes_F U)$  in the finite dimension case ?

Comment: Write some vector $v\in K\otimes_F V$ as a sum $v = \sum \alpha_i v_i$ where $\alpha_i\in K$ and $v_i\in V$. Since $\psi$ is $K$-linear we have $\psi(v) = \sum\alpha_i\psi(v_i)$. So $\psi$ is determined by $Hom_F(V,U)$. In other words, we can write $\psi = \varphi_K$ for some $\phi\in Hom_F(V,U)$. This is kind of a slippery argument, but the idea is that extending scalars to $K$ doesn't affect that the morphisms are still determined by morphisms over $F$.

Comment: Once you have $\psi = \varphi_K$, you have the pre-image $1\otimes \varphi$ that maps to it, since $\phi_K$ is determined by $\varphi$.